# Encode an ascii string into a decimal or binary vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, binary, decimal, ascii, filepath

I need to store a string representing a full path with only using a vector of numbers, which I can convert back to the original full path. I tried to use `double`and `char`:

```
s=double('Full/path')
s = 70   117   108   108    47   112    97   116   104

string_rev = char(s)
string_rev = Full/path
```

Unfortunately, `s` is a double array, with different length of numbers. Once merged, I will not be able to convert it back. I could add zeros as a delimiter, but this seems not to be very elegant.

Is there any other way to store a string encoded in numbers which I can use to encode and reverse afterwards?
To clarify the final goal:

'Full' --> 70117108108 --> 'Full'

**Edit:**
Why do I need this?
I need to store the path in a file which only accepts integers. Once I saved the file, I would like to be able to load it and extract the full path from the integer.

Comment: the char(s) part seems to work and the `s` is a double array 1xN. what isint working with those? What do oyu mean with "different length of numbers"

Comment: what is your exact problem ? the fact that some of the character end up with different number length in the double array (ex: `F=>70` shorter than `u=>117`). This does not cause any problem to convert it back to string ...

Comment: I need to store the path as a single number. So if I have F-->70 and u-->117, I need to be able to store it as 70117.

Comment: is 070117 an  option? (taking leading zeors for numbers <100) that would make the task way easier

Comment: May we ask what the purpose of this is? Why do you need to represent the string by a single integer?

Comment: leading shouldn't work in MATLAB as matlab automatically removes all leading zeros. Delimiting with 0's should also cause issues as e.g.`l=108`.

I believe the best practice would be to add 100 to each number and then subtract later on. This will ensure that all ascii characters are stored in numbers between 100 and 999.

Comment: What about using `fprintf`, e.g. `fprintf('%03d', char( 'Full/path' ) )`. No need for hacky workarounds.

Comment: @Skogsv: Why do I need this?
I need to store the path in a file which only accepts integers. Once I saved the file, I would like to be able to load it and extract the full path from the integer.

Comment: @MatthiasW. How can I get back from the output back to the full path?

Comment: Use `sscanf` or `fscanf`... `foo = char('070117108108047112097116104'); char( sscanf( foo, '%03d' ) )'`

Comment: "a file which only accepts integers" sounds strange, anyway. So you may have problems with integers being way to big and having a leading zero. Strange concept.

Comment: agreed, why don't you simply store each of the integers in s as their own variables in the file `a1 a2 a3 etc`?

Comment: "_a file which only accepts integers_" ??? that makes no sense at all. Do you mean a _binary_ file ? or are your "integers" be stored in plain text format in a text file? Anyway, @MatthiasW. solution does exactly what you're asking for at the moment.